# Repeating reference to CoreData Entity when debugging object in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data

I may be simply understanding this incorrectly, but when I created an `Exercise` entity and looked at it contents in the debugger I get this repeating reference to the Entity type.

[image]

The Exercise+CoreDataProperties file is standard:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension Exercise {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Exercise> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Exercise>(entityName: "Exercise")
}

@NSManaged public var exerciseDuration: Int16
@NSManaged public var repeatNo: Int16
@NSManaged public var restDuration: Int16
@NSManaged public var exerciseName: String
@NSManaged public var id: UUID
@NSManaged public var associatedWorkout: NSSet?

}

// MARK: Generated accessors for associatedWorkout
extension Exercise {

@objc(addAssociatedWorkoutObject:)
@NSManaged public func addToAssociatedWorkout(_ value: WorkoutSet)

@objc(removeAssociatedWorkoutObject:)
@NSManaged public func removeFromAssociatedWorkout(_ value: WorkoutSet)

@objc(addAssociatedWorkout:)
@NSManaged public func addToAssociatedWorkout(_ values: NSSet)

@objc(removeAssociatedWorkout:)
@NSManaged public func removeFromAssociatedWorkout(_ values: NSSet)

}

extension Exercise : Identifiable {

}
```

And here is the xcdatamodeld config:
[image]

Any ideas why I cannot view the values of the object in debug mode once I've created it? Have I done something in my code to cause this repetition?

Comment: You haven't done anything wrong in your code to produce the repetition. You can't view the data in the debugger like that. You can print or log it. Also, Core Data managed objects are identifiable, so you don't need the UUID. Just use `.objectID'.

Comment: Thanks @Yrb I appreciate the input. I’ll keep that in my notes for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables view you're using can't see into the values of properties of managed objects (or of most objects). If you want to inspect the property values, use the debug console. When you're stopped on the line in your screenshot, you should be able to use `po newExercise` to see properties of `newExercise`, or you can use commands like `po newExercise.exerciseName` to see individual property values.